# Clean-up a file

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, sharpsvn

I would like to perform the action on a file without affecting the rest of the files in the same version-controlled folder.

Is it possible to clean-up a particular file?

Comment: The "clean up" menu in TortoiseSVN joins a number of assorted options that are not really related. Which one are you interested in?

Comment: Do you want to "revert" a single file, i.e. remove all you local changes? "clean up" is a command to repair a broken working copy, it doesn't make sense to do it on one file only.

Comment: @Ben, I unserdtand. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`svn cleanup FILE` doesn't have any sense at all - it's always **global** restore|repair operation